# Anti de Sitter metric with signature +---

Tags: general-relativity, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

Most of the textbooks write EFE
$$ R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=-\Lambda g_{\mu\nu} $$
With metric signature $-+++$. However, I am using the other signature $+---$, but when I solve for Anti de Sitter spacetime I get the metric
$$ ds^2=f(r)dt^2-(f(r))^{-1}dr^2-r^2d\Omega^2$$
where $f=1-r^2/R^2$ which is clearly for de Sitter spacetime!!

What is the problem?

p.s.
I suspect there is a problem with the EFE form in this ethical signature.

Comment: Einstein's equations look the same regardless of signature. The metric you wrote is de Sitter for real $R$ and anti-de Sitter for imaginary $R$.

Comment: At first, I proposed $f(r)=1+\alpha r^2$ then the equation gave me $3\alpha=\Lambda$ which would give real $R$ for Anti de Sitter instead.

Comment: I think you mean real $R^2$.

Comment: @Kushina Uzumaki You can verify your calculation using the GREAT.m package in mathematica, since most of the time, calculations like solving EFE are lengthy and prone to errors